# QImage RGB32 to QImage RGB24, bad result with some kind of image

Tags: c++, qt5, qimage

I try to convert the `QImage` with RGB32 to `QImage` with RGB24. 
My code doesn't work in this case:

When the image has an additional 1024 bytes in the BMP header, the size of the image is X*Y*3+54+an unknown 1024 byte.

**The strange thing is that the code works if the image resolution x == resolution y, for example: 512x512 or 1024x1024. Whatever the situation: when I have or don't have the additional 1024 Byte in the header.**

If the BMP does not have the additional 1024 byte in the header, every thing works fine even if resolution x is different than resolution y. My code :

```
QImage * img=new QImage("test.jpg");//load img as RGB32 32bit per pixel whatever the format of input

QImage * tmp_img=new QImage(img->width(),img->height(),QImage::Format_RGB888);// image dest 24bit per pixel

     uchar * ptr1=img->bits();
     uchar * ptr2=tmp_img->bits();

     for( int k1=0,k2=0;k1<img->width()*img->height()*4;k1+=4,k2+=3)//increment k1 by 4 because img format is RGB32
                                                  //increment k2 by 3 because tmp_img format is RGB888
     {
         ptr2[k2]=ptr1[k1];
         ptr2[k2+1]=ptr1[k1+1];
         ptr2[k2+2]=ptr1[k1];
     }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removed old answer.

Why not simply do this:

```
QImage img2 = img->convertToFormat(QImage::Format_RGB888);
```

Comment: QImage img2 = img->convertToFormat(QImage::Format_RGB888); work at 100%, but i need to understand the why, the logic behind, whats wrong with img ho have additional 1024 byte in header.

Comment: When you load `img` the format is not RGB32 as in your comment.  It is based on the header within the file.  I would guess that your file is not storing pixels in RGB32 and therefore the QImage does not use this format.  You could try inspecting the value of `img->format()`

Comment: ok in this case why if a adjust the image using paint, gimp... to 512x512, it work perfect but 512x513 its wrong, whats the relation with the resolution?,  img->format()return RGB32, whatever the image the Qt load it in RGB32 even if it's gray or RGb24... always RGB32.

Comment: This is a great example of why you should use existing methods rather than attempt to write your own for common functions.  Your code will have more bugs in than the widely used method.  `ptr2[k2+2]=ptr1[k1];` is wrong for a start.

Comment: i will do converting+edge detect+ filtering+compression in one loop, for time efficient.

Comment: If you really need to access the pixels individually, then I would recommend using the `pixel` and `setPixel` methods of QImage rather than directly manipulating the raw data.  This will hide any format issues from your code.